# Adding new div to row causes wrapping

Tags: html, css, ruby, sinatra, word-wrap

I have some problems with divs in a Bootstrap row wrapping when I don't want them to. I'm designing a Mastermind game (Sinatra/Ruby/JS, for educational purposes) that has, in the "new guess" row, cells for three pegs and then the "check guess" button—so, four divs.

Below that, after the first guess, a table shows up with old guesses and the black and white pegs evaluating the guesses. This doesn't show up until the user makes the first guess.

To the table with the old guesses, I decided to add a new div, for the number of guesses so far. Since adding that, to make things line up nicely, I added an empty cell to the beginning of the "new guess" row. But now, when you start a new game—before the table with the old guesses shows up—the last cell in the "new guess" row wraps. It looks fine after you make that first guess. The "new guess" row is exactly the width that it would have if it simply lacked the newly-added empty cell.

I cannot for the life of me figure out why this cell insists on wrapping. Width is not set anywhere and the divs are set to `float: left`. I tried `white-space: nowrap` as someone suggested but that doesn't help.

You can see the problem [here](http://secure-eyrie-53019.herokuapp.com/)—the checkmark is supposed to be at the right side of the table, not below it. If you try an answer (click the peg holes to cycle through colors) and submit an answer, you can see what it's supposed to look like. The main view (which embeds "guessrow" and the "oldrows" erbs) is [here](https://github.com/globewalldesk/Mastermind/blob/master/views/main.erb). The "guessrow" is [here](https://github.com/globewalldesk/Mastermind/blob/master/views/guessrow.erb) and the "oldrows" is [here](https://github.com/globewalldesk/Mastermind/blob/master/views/oldrows.erb). The css (scss) is [here](https://github.com/globewalldesk/Mastermind/blob/master/public/assets/custom.scss).

Comment: Can you please create a simple example outside of your codebase? I think you can go about this in a better way. You shouldn't need to use nowrap. That is for inline elements - not floats. Your parent element is unaware of how floats work (once you float it's children - they are no longer in the natural flow) and should have a clearfix - or (overflow hidden or float itself) like suggested - but that would likely not be the most ideal layout technique - depending. PS (you don't need to specify 'plain' JavaScript. ; )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please set `overflow:hidden;` with a class on the form tag (to clear the floats).

*Explanation*

As you may have noticed, CSS is very complex and hard to deeply understand to anybody, me also. I try to explain why my suggestion works. The `.board` is absolutely positioned so it shrinkwraps. If the content has no intrinsic width, tends to break into a new line. If the floats have no clearing elements (self clearing parent or clearing sibling element) they remain out of the normal document flow, aligning horizontally if there is enough space. Self clearing parent (in this case the form) establishes a new block formatting context which  encompasses child elements elements, taking the necessary horizontal space (if available). As a rule of thumb, when you float something you need also to clear the float, otherwise you may face unexpected layout behaviour. Following link summarizes well the concept of floating: [All About Floats](https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/)

Comment: Thanks! Nailed it! Can you explain what you mean by "to clear the floats"? I don't understand why this works. I sort of understand what `overflow:hidden` does (https://css-tricks.com/the-css-overflow-property/) but I don't see what it has to do with this div wrapping.

Comment: Please check the above explanation.

Answer (score 1):

In your code there is one empty div created see below

```
<div class="pegcell empty" style=""></div>
```

if you remove it or hide it it will fix your problem

try this code and see

```
.pegcell.empty {
    display: none;
}
```

see img [image]

Comment: In other words, get rid of the div I want to be there. This fixes the problem when there are no guesses, but introduces a new problem (unaligned columns) when the first guess is shown. I could use JS to hide it when there are no guesses, but that would look clumsy...